# How to extends 3rd party typescript interface from a library?

Tags: typescript

Say I want to add new attribute to an express instance in typescript. For example, I usually do something like this in express application for testing purpose.

```
app = express();
app.__listener = app.listen();
```

But in typescript I need to define an interface that is like express instance but have `__listener` field.

I read some article [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html). we can do something like:

```
interface Document {
    createElement(tagName: any): Element;
}
interface Document {
    createElement(tagName: "div"): HTMLDivElement;
    createElement(tagName: "span"): HTMLSpanElement;
}
```

but I'm lost at importing express interface then merge it with my own added field.
Is this case actually possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Express declares a global namespace with interfaces that are destined to be augmented.

```
import express from 'express'
import { Server } from "http";

declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface Application { 
      __listener: Server
    }
  }
}
const app = express();
app.__listener = app.listen();
```